# Yeast Ok After Being Near Freezing?

Tags: yeast, storage

I have some California Ale Yeast WLP001 that I accidentally put in a corner of my fridge that is near freezing and it has been there for about a month. It's still in liquid form, so I think it should still be ok, but any thoughts?

I'm doing a starter now, which should help it out, but I'd like to know as soon as possible since I'm planning on brewing tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The starter will tell the story.  If it froze, you might have ruptured yeast cell walls and reduced the viability.  A starter will show you how healthy it is and build new cells.  If the starter looks good, you'll be fine.

Comment: I figured I had nothing to lose other than some DME and a little bit of my time, so I went for it with the starter. Fortunately, the yeast was fine and 24 hours later, brew-day was a success.